# typescript no reconoce archivos .graphql y no los incluye en la carpeta build

Tags: nodejs, typescript, graphql

estoy empezando un backen con graphql y estoy utilizando archivos `.graphql` cargandolos con `graphql-tools`, mi servidor esta creado con node, utilizo typescript como lenguale de desarrollo, de esta manera leo el archivo graphql

```
import { join } from 'path';
import { stitchSchemas } from "@graphql-tools/stitch";
import { loadSchemaSync } from "@graphql-tools/load";
import { GraphQLFileLoader } from "@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader";
import { addResolversToSchema } from "@graphql-tools/schema";

//AUTHENTICATION RESOLVERS AND SCHEMAS
const authentication = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, "./typeDefs/authentication.graphql"), {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
});

const schemaWithResolvers = addResolversToSchema({
  schema: authentication,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      ping: ()=> "pong"
    }
  },
});

// SETUP SUBSCHEMA CONFIGURATIONS
export const AuthenticationSubSchema = { schema: schemaWithResolvers };

// BUILD THE COMBINED SCHEMA
export const gatewaySchema = stitchSchemas({
  subschemas: [AuthenticationSubSchema],
});
```

funciona, pero a la hora de compilar, si reviso la carpeta `build`, no se esta integrando el archivo `.graphql`, por lo tanto la consola me da error, pero si agrego manualmente la carpeta `typeDefs` y dentro agrego el archivo `authentication.graphql`, funciona, pero realizar esto cada vez que agregue cambios en el archivo sinceramente es tedioso, como puedo hacer que typescript o tsc-watch escuche esos archivos y los incluya ?

Comment: estuve leyendo la doc y e inclui como dice los archivos, pero el error que recibo es que tsconfig.json solo lee archivos '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'

Comment: no pude solucionar el problema aun

Answer (score 0):

Así soluciono yo al momento de hacer el **build
ncp** es un paquete para copiar los archivos, también puedes copiar la carpeta entera si son varios archivos

```
"build": "tsc  && ncp ./src/schemas/schemas.graphql ./dist/src/schemas/schemas.graphql"
```